# Convert objects present in an object to NULL value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, object

I have the following object names $scope.parameters. When i execute console.log as shown below, i get this result

```
console.log($scope.parameters);
```

Result

```
Object { Name: "Diana", id: 234, Size: Object, Location: Object, Details: "none" }
Name: "Diana"
id: 234,
Size: Object
Location: Object
Details: "none"
```

As the result shows the elements Size and Location as Object, i want it to be replaced with null. Also, i want it to be dynamic. for e.g. if any of the above elements are Object, it should replace it to null automatically.

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you would want this?

Comment: I am passing null values to backend. if i pop out the window and then pass, those null values gets converted to Object and i get an error

Comment: what on earth does *"pop out the window"* mean? Please take some time to review [ask]

Comment: I am using golden layout with angularjs. It has a popout feature where we can seperate a particular section of UI and work as if they are 2 seperate windows

Comment: and what is the relevance of that to the question asked?

Comment: @charlietfl- popout the tab and the value changes from null to Object. I want it to remain as null even after popout. Thats y i am trying to convert all objects to null

Comment: @charlietfl- learn something from deep mehta. instead of asking irrelevant questions, we would be glad if you help on the question itself. use case and where i am using it, y i am using it. sounds so stupid.....

Comment: what have you tried? it's not overly difficult to check type of a property. And don't be ignorant to people asking questions that are intended to try to help. This isn't a code writing service and you are expected to attempt to find solutions yourself first. right now the question shows zero attempts to solve or any research effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test out each key of the object with its type if object make them null

```
if (Object.getPrototypeOf($scope.parameters.Size) === Object.prototype) {
    // True if its object change it to null
    $scope.parameters.Size = null;
} else {
    // do nothing 
}
```

Make a function which takes parameters to test it out and return.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.forEach($scope.parameters, function(value, key) {

    if(typeof value === "object"){
    console.log(key);
        $scope.parameters[key] = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide some additional details instead of a snippet only in order to improve the answer's quality.